# What is the meaning of brAhmana, as mentioned in Rig Veda II.36.5?

Tags: rig-veda, brahman, indra

Rig Veda [II.36.5](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02036.htm) says

> eṣa sya te tanvo nṛmṇavardhanaḥ saha ojaḥ pradivi bāhvorhitaḥ |
>
> tubhyaṃ suto maghavan tubhyamābhṛtastvamasya brāhmanādā tṛpat piba ||

[Translation of Ralph T.H. Griffith](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02036.htm) is as follows:

> This is the strengthener of thy body's manly might: strength, victory
> for all time are placed within thine arms. Pressed for thee, Maghavan,
> it is offered unto thee: drink from the chalice ***of this Brahman***, drink
> thy fill.

Translation of [H.H. Wilson](http://vedicheritage.gov.in/flipbook/Rigveda_Samhita_English_Vol_II/#book/211) (p.183) is as follows:

> This (libation). Indra. augmenter of thy bodily (vigour). favourable
> of old to the resistless strength of (thy) arms: it is effused.
> Meghavan. for thee. it is brought to thee ***from the Brahmana***. do thou
> drink and be satisfied.

---

Both the translations are giving the meaning of from **brAhmana**.  Though the word बरह्मा - brAhman was mentioned in II.1.2, it indicates the Almighty.  However, here the word **brAhmana** was used.

In Rig Veda [X.90.12](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10090.htm), **बराह्मण - brAhmana** was used indicating one from Varna system, along with kshatriya, Vyasya and Sudra.

However, in the mantra in question, the word **brAhmana** alone was used that to requesting Indra to take oblation from a **brAhmana**.

I don't think it was used with the meaning of Varna system.

Can anyone throw light, please?

Answer (score 2):

The verse is talking about Somarasa, drinking which Lord Indra gets strength and victory etc.

It is the vArna only because brAhmans offers Somarasa during yajnA to all deities. The same verse when gets translated in Hindi, referred the word brAhmanas as "jnani people". In fact, There is one yajnA named Somayajna itself in which soma rasa is used for the offerings and done by brAhmanas only. 
Quoting the text from the article ["What is somayajna"](http://www.somayagam.org/what_is_somayagam.html?id=somayagam) :

> Soma yagam is a highly spiritual and effective ritual performed as prescribed in the Vedas. This lasts for six days. This Yagam is called Soma Yagam because Soma rasam (juice) is used as the main oblation. The Soma plant, the king of medicinal herbs, is said to be ‘relished by the celestials’. **In Soma Yagam there is the full complement of priests, with each of them being is assisted by three others. In all sixteen priests participate in the Soma Yagam. Agni stoma which is the first of the seven soma Yagams is the ‘Prakriti’ (archetype) and the other six are its ‘Vikriti’.**

Comment: I had already mentioned that the usage of brAhmana May not be Varna basis. The sages who composed those mantras may have different meanings for that usage

Comment: @srimannarayanakv The meaning is straightforward regardless your disagreement "the usage of brAhmana May not be Varna basis". That's what I am trying to point out here.

Comment: As far as I understood, the mantras of Rig Veda were composed by rishies.  I don't think they would have used one word in such a manner, which can be understood by all.

Comment: When it gets translated in Hindi it means "ज्ञानी जनों"

Comment: May be you are right.  You can revise your answer duly incorporating this.  @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Sriman Done, please check.

Comment: Your statement that **It is the vArna only..." is not in concurrence with another statement **referred the word brAhmanas as "jnani people"**.  Please check.  Further, please remember that Soma is not physical in Rig Vedic Sense, but it is only BLISS mentioned as an epithet.  Please check @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: Brahmanada = eternal bliss when you perform maghavan you get brahmanada @srimannarayanakv

Answer (score 0):

Apart from in Rig Veda II.36.5, as mentioned in my question, the word ***brahmana*** was used in Rig Veda, here and there.

---

Rig Veda [II.43.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02043.htm), dedicated to **Kapiñjala**, says

> udghāteva śakune sāma ghāyasi ***brahmaputra*** iva savaneṣu śaṃsasi |
> vṛṣeva vājī śiśumatīrapītyā sarvato naḥ śakune bhadramā vada viśvato
> naḥ śakune puṇyamā vada ||
>
> Thou like the chanter-priest chantest the Sāma, Bird; thou singest at
> libations like a ***Brahman's son***.
>
> Even as a vigorous horse when he comes
> near the mare, announce to us good fortune, Bird, on every side,
> proclaim in all directions happy luck, O Bird.

---

In the mantra the word [brahmaputra](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02043.htm), bold portion, was used.

The ***brahmaputra*** - brAhman's son, will sing Sāma Veda at libations.

---

The major mantras of Sama Veda are from Rig Veda.  As mentioned in the question, I don't think the word ***brAhmana*** had been used with the meaning of Varna system, as the mantra was composed by a Sage, who was a ***dhrastha*** that heard from the DIVINE, apart from being a poet.

So that cannot and will not, in my opinion, use a word to indicate something, which is not DIVINE.

Further, in the 2nd mantra from Rig Veda II.43.2, the word used was **brahmaputra** - **Brahman's son**.  It must be viewed in esoteric sense only, which will mean only the **son of Almighty**, ie., a **brAhman** by himself, in spiritual sense.

---

So the word **brAhmana** was used in Rig Veda in the sense of a **Realised one or Jnani** only.

Comment: Here brahma putra are Garuda, Sesha, Rudra..  we have to check who is abhimani devata for sama that is Rudra.. Brahma putra is Rudra @srimannarayanakv

Comment: @PrasannaR: We should not mix up Veda with Puranas.  The meanings of epithets used in Rig Veda are used compared to that in Puranas.